# apex_web_service.make_rest_request POST has bad json or returns ORA-06502 numeric or value error

Tags: json, oracle, rest, web-services, oracle-apex

I cannot get successful POST /authentication/login with E-verify/DHS using PLSQL using `apex_web_service.make_rest_request()`.  I tried in Apex first but got numeric/value error and swtiched to PLSQL to debug.  It uses json.  Apex version is 4.2.  I can get a GET to work, but that does not use headers or parms.

1. If  specify `p_parm_name` using `string_to_table()` or using `p_parm_name` by specifying each array value separately, then I get `{"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError"}`
2. If I specify `p_body` then i get an ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.
3. If I specify `p_body` but use wrong password, I get (what I think is) non-ascii response like the following:
4. If I use varchar2 instead of clob in various spots I get same errors
5. If I use postman with the same p_body then it works!!

So of course I'd love for this code to work, but in lieu of that, HOW DO I SEE THE REQUEST coming from Oracle/Apex so I can confirm what the json looks like (for #1 above)?  Thanks!

Here is code.

```
      l_parm_names  apex_application_global.vc_arr2;  
      l_parm_values apex_application_global.vc_arr2;   
      l_resp_clob        clob;
      l_resp_length      integer;
      l_body_varchar2    varchar2(4000);
      l_body_clob        clob;
    begin  
      l_parm_names(1) := 'username';  
      l_parm_values(1) := 'user1234';  
      l_parm_names(2) := 'password';  
      l_parm_values(2) := 'pass1234';
      l_body_varchar2  := '{"username":"user1234","password":"pass1234"}';
      l_body_clob      := to_clob(l_body_varchar2);
      apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete();
      apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';  
      apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';
      l_resp_clob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
         p_url => 'https://stage-everify*******login',  
         p_http_method => 'POST',
--         p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('username:password'),
--         p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('user1234:pass1234')
--         p_parm_name => l_parm_names,
--         p_parm_value => l_parm_values
         p_body => l_body_clob
         );   
       INSERT INTO ev_clob (body, resp, dte, note)
        VALUES (l_body_clob, l_resp_clob, SYSDATE, 'Stack Script 1');  commit;
    end;
```

Comment: You can call the Apex DEBUG api to log a message containing your request.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/MESSAGE-Procedure.htm#AEAPI29228

Comment: Hello Mark, I moved the code into a page process in apex to wrap the make_rest_request with the apex_debug.message().  It logs the response, but not the request.  Please advise how to log the request if you think it would work that way.  Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by, "I can get a GET to work, but that does not use headers or parms." GET can use headers and params, but it's not typically used to send a body. Have you gotten this to work with a command-line tool like cURL? If so, show us that command (after obfuscating anything sensitive) so we have something to work back from.

Comment: Hello Dan:  For the GET I just wanted to show that firewall/ACL works and t that I am not sure I'm setting headers/parms correctly on the POST.  I haven't used curl , but tried and both POST/GET returned the same error.  We use Oracle Wallet and have certificate, so guessing curl does not know where that stuff is and is reason for error.  Here is my curl and response for the GET...  `curl https://stage-everify.uscis.gov/api/v30/health   

curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to stage-everify.uscis.gov:443`

Comment: here is curl from working Postman example `curl -X POST \
  https://stage-everify.uscis.gov/api/v30/authentication/login \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 289' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: cases-ui-access-token=' \
  -H 'Host: stage-everify.uscis.gov' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: *' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \`

Comment: curl part 2...`  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F username=* \
  -F 'password=*'`

Comment: I am pretty new to Apex  Could you please tell me where you added above code.. I am also trying to call a rest API from apex

Comment: Hi. I had the same problem when content-type application/json, i work with : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and works for me when using p_parm_name and p_parm_value. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the json in this way

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN l_cursor FOR
    SELECT e.empno AS "employee_number",
           e.ename AS "employee_name",
           e.deptno AS "department_number"
    FROM   emp e
    WHERE  rownum <= 2;

  APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output;

  APEX_JSON.open_object;
  APEX_JSON.write('employees', l_cursor);
  APEX_JSON.close_object;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(APEX_JSON.get_clob_output);
  APEX_JSON.free_output;
END;
/
```

Here you can find more information
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29737

```
BEGIN
  apex_json.open_object; -- {
  apex_json.open_object('obj'); -- "obj": {
  apex_json.write('obj-attr', 'value'); -- "obj-attr": "value"
  apex_json.close_all; -- }}
END;
```

Comment: Hello Enrique:  Thanks for the response.  It appears that `apex_json` is unfortunately not available in Apex 4.2.  The documentation you linked is version 5.0.  Thanks anyway.